# What is the difference between Google Web Toolkit and Google Apps Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, gwt

What is the difference between the two platforms/frameworks, besides that one uses Java, and the other Python?  What are the different purposes/uses of each?  I ask this because I'm trying to write a simple web app, and am not sure which one to use.  I have had some experience with GWT people, but prefer Python and am wondering if GAE is easier to work with.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

GWT is a Java library.  You write Java code using the GWT API.  That java code gets compiled into javascript that can be run in a web browser.  The compilation step is provided by software in the GWT.

GAE is completely different.  GAE is a server platform for deploying web applications to Google's server infrastructure.  You can use GWT in a GAE app; you do not have to do this.  You can create a GAE app that does not use GWT.

The only thing these two technologies have in common is the 'G'.

Comment: Well, and 'J'. Both GWT-based clients and GAE-based servers can be written in Java. Your Java UI skills (e.g. creating event-driven interfaces) and your knowledge of Servets can be applied in GWT and GAE, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

GWT is an Ajax library provided by Google like Dojo/Jquery came up. But it came with a prerequisite with Java as server side component unlike other Ajax (Javascript) frameworks.

Contrarily GAE is a Cloud computing platform which helps you build cloud applications on Google Cloud via GAE.  This is a total platform of GAE is provided as a service. In this platform you can code your application on Python or Java (currently). Database would be Google's Data Store API (Big Table, a Google's Hierarchial Database). It is in the form of ORMs. Views can be HTML or XML

Comment: GWT certainly does NOT require the server side to have anything to do with Java. GWT is first and foremost a framework for building sophisticated client applications which run in browsers. It gives you facilities to communicate with a Servet-based server application, however it also provides you with everything you need to connect to any backend.